# In Rollup config, how does one use moduleSideEffects to import side effect files AND their dependencies?

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

Many things are being included in my bundles that I do not want because they are being considered as side-effectful when they are not. Promise calls and the like. So I am experimenting with setting `moduleSideEffects` to a function* that marks only those files that really have side effects as side-effectful. However, I'm running into a problem: Rollup will not include a file marked as side-effectful if all it's dependencies are not side-effectful.

```
// a.js
export function se() {
   console.log('Side effect');
}

// b.js
import { se } from 'b.js';
se();
```

I mark `b.js` as side-effectful because I only want `a.js` to be included where `b.js` is included. Now consider these two possible `main.js` files:

```
// main.js
import 'a.js';
```

Here `a.js` is not included in the bundle, correctly, as it is not side-effectful.

```
// main.js
import 'b.js';
```

Here neither `a.js` or `b.js` are included, even though `b.js` side-effectful. When I mark `a.js` as side-effectful they are both included, however that means it is also included in the previous version of `main.js`.

I'm having trouble working out if this is a bug or intended behaviour, or how to work around it.

Rollup 2.21.0

(* I use a function because I could not get an array of relative, absolute or blob paths to work as `moduleSideEffects`, which is a separate problem. I'm obviously missing something about how they should be defined.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is that `moduleSideEffects: true` only switches on the *test* for side-effects, it doesn't mark every module as side-effectful. So if there are no side-effects the file will, correctly, still not be included.

Comment: In my case when set moduleSideEffects: true , the build include unnecessary icons file

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#treeshake

To specify which modules having side effect, you can do as follow:

```js
{
...
  treeshake: {
    moduleSideEffects: ['@saleshood/design-system/dist/style.css'],
  },
}
```

Notice: the string params refer to modules that have side effect NOT its consumer. For example, for this file to keep loading the `css` file:

```js
// src/hocs/DSHOC.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd';

import '@saleshood/design-system/dist/style.css';

export const DSHOC = {...}
```

Use

```js
moduleSideEffects: ['@saleshood/design-system/dist/style.css'],
```

Not

```js
moduleSideEffects: ['src/hocs/DSHOC.tsx'],
```